# How to click on 1st button when there are Multiple buttons same value same name

Tags: javascript

If multiple input submit classes are referred using single code how to click on 1st one ???
Following code is used by all input submit classes

```
<div class="call-to-action call-to-action-f101">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Reservar" name="addToCartButtonSelected"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I really don't want to click that link..

Comment: That link is scary!!!!

Comment: You need to include more html. Your button input doesn't seem to have a class, but is each button input in its own div?

Comment: I havent' clicked the link. But, to access the first element out of many referred using the same class, you need to use `.class-name:first-child`.

Comment: That's a really busy page, and it's hard to tell what you actually want to do here. You should really include some example code in your question.

Comment: Here is HTML Code
<!-- Object name: call-to-action View name: F101_add_to_basket_list --><div class="call-to-action call-to-action-f101">

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Reservar" name="addToCartButtonSelected"/>


</div><!-- End Object -->

Comment: ^ edit your question don'e post relevant code in the comments

Comment: the question has been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`button` is an actual HTML element, and there are no `<button>` elements on that page. I assume you mean the inputs with the class "submit". To get an array of all those buttons, you can use the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('submit')
```

And then to click the first, you can just do:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0].click()
```

Comment: all submit  are referring same code so its clicking on all

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of all elements with the given class name, in the order they appear on the page. The `[0]` means we're accessing the first index of the array, which would be the first time the element is on the page. Calling `.click()` on that will only apply to that one element.